# The SSH Tunnel could not authenticate with the remote host

Tags: sequelpro

I am trying to connect Laravel Forge database from Sequel pro. I am getting the "The SSH Tunnel could not authenticate with the remote host. Please check your password and ensure you still have access" error.

Initially I was asked to enter the paraphrase. I got the same result even with the right paraphrase.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you added your public key to the server? You should try to login with ssh first and then test the whole mysql connection

Comment: I did. I can access using ssh forge@ip . I need to enter the paraphrase to connect to the server.

Comment: Probably your client requires authentication using a certificate (the ssh key row).